# Changing the field height in a TFS field

Tags: tfs, workitem

How can I change the height of a field in the TFS process template editor? If I stack two HTML type fields on top of each other the default rendering of the work item shows the first field about 20% and the second field about 80%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have published a post on how to do just this:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/eranruso/archive/2010/04/06/how-to-set-tfs-work-item-field-size.aspx

Eran Ruso